# IntelliJ stopped auto saving - how to fix / find cause

Tags: intellij-idea

Question is what steps can I take to debug this?

It does very occasionally auto-save itself, but not on change of active window as previously. I can't yet reproduce a specific cause of this (very occasional) autosave.

I have all auto-save options as per default:

[image]

I recently did brew upgrade including `fswatch`. Would I be right in assuming IntelliJ would use its own though, not brew's `fswatch` if installed?

Another possibility is it's a Mac OS Privacy thing; a Catalina update seems to have broken one program which expected disk access to be available, now it's not; not sure if Intellij has lost some kind of OS permission to do (auto) saves(?), while this doesn't affect a user issued command to save, which works fine.

Comment: How do you know it does not auto save? Please describe like the sequence of events and the expected/actual result.

Comment: Does e.g. File | Save All action help? Do you use RDP or X forwarding?

Comment: "Save All" does work, and that is how I am now working. I know it is not auto-saving because other programs (a separate Git client, a hot reloading web server, and a hot reloading js compile step) do not pick up the changes (unless I do "Save All" *manually*). When I do save all manually, all of those programs trigger as normal - their file watch is working fine. I don't use either of the things you mentioned.

Comment: Do you store all files on a local disk? Any symlinks? I think more details is needed to tell what might the issue be (including scenarios and exact steps before issue happens, the diagnostics info - Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action). Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with this information. Thanks.

Comment: I found the cause, which is very bizarre but reproducible  -  I noticed that auto-save had returned to normal, and asked myself what had I changed recently which could have caused it. The answer is I had deactivated the accessibility keyboard. Out of sheer idle curiousity I decided to test if that was the cause, and it is. --- If I "Show Keyboard Viewer" (this is with Dwell actions on, which I've been trying out), the Intellij Auto save stops functioning. If I deselect  "Show keyboard viewer", it immediately returns to normal (i.e. save occurs on change of active window).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I could not reproduce with a simple scenario: when I change the file and switch from the application and back - it auto-saves the file. Could you please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with exact steps (what files and how you are changing) and after what actions the changes are not picked up. And your IDE logs attached (Help | Show Log In Finder action).